# Flash: Find actionscript for a movie clip

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

I've been asked to transform an existing flash application to HTML5/JavaScript and make some improvements.

I don't know Flash very well and am having problems trying to get the code for 3 movie scripts.

[image: Movie clips in library]

As you can see there are 3 movie clips called Animation_[high|low|medium]_mc and I expected to find the code for them in the actions panel.

[image: Actions panel]

However I cannot see any symbols with the same name.

Is there any way to get access to the code behind these 3 movie clips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any code anywhere in this file (via Actions panel)? Its also possible for the code to be "imported" from an external **.as** file. Press **CTRL+F3** does the "Properties" have a name in the "Class" section? If so that's the AS file that controls everything. Otherwise check main timeline frames for code (ie: the Stage not a specific MC's timeline). That failing just check all MCs (tedious & no professional would have made it like that but y'never know). Also by checking other MCs you can see if the code is really elsewhere instead of the high/low/medium MCs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check it out tonight and let you know.